# Unable to load the mojo 'test' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20'

Tags: java, maven

Проблема заключается в невозможности собрать проект Maven.

У заказчика нет на машине интернета. Репозиторий - копия моего, кот. у них лежит в папке пользователя + свой. При запуске тестов с помощью

```html
mvn -o clean test
```

появляется ошибка

```html
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ UFOTests ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin not present
 at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:147)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:519)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefireReportParameters
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromImport(ClassRealm.java:380)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:38)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromImport(ClassRealm.java:380)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:38)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:139)
 ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireReportParameters
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
 ... 66 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.634 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-27T15:30:18+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/292M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project UFOTests: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20'. A required class is missing: org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefireReportParameters
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.20/maven-surefire-plugin-2.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.20/maven-surefire-common-2.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.20/surefire-booter-2.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.6/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.6/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.20/surefire-api-2.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-logger-api/2.20/surefire-logger-api-2.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/ufo_bamboo_agent/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.3/maven-plugin-annotations-3.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Откатывали проект до старых библиотек, на кот. в свое время запускалось;
делали

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

на моем компе и переносили этот репозиторий со всеми решенными зависимостями на компьютер заказчика.
Не помогло.
Физически этот плагин на диске есть. На моем компьютере не воспроизводится.

POM такой:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId></groupId>
 <artifactId></artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

<!-- для отправки на RP -->
 <!-- repositories>
  <repository>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
   </snapshots>
   <id>bintray-epam-reportportal</id>
   <name>bintray</name>
   <url>http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories-->

 <dependencies>
  <!-- для отправки на RP -->
  <!-- dependency>
   <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
   <artifactId>agent-java-testng</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
   <artifactId>logger-java-logback</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
   <artifactId>logger-java-log4j</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.1</version>
  </dependency-->
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.25</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.25</version>
  </dependency> 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.1</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
   <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.4</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
     <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>6.2.0.jre8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
   <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.4</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.8</source>
     <target>1.8</target>
     <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <configuration>
     <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
     <skip>false</skip>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>example.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
     <properties>
      <property>
       <name>listener</name>
       <!-- ReportPortalTestNGListener - для отправки на RP -->
       <value><!-- com.epam.reportportal.testng.ReportPortalTestNGListener,-->
       org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter</value>
      </property>
     </properties>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, у заказчика было вот что:

1. В переменной среды JAVA_HOME не перешли на jdk.
2. В конфиге мавена в сеттингс были вписаны реквизиты собственного репозитория.